# Sum with inner join in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm working with PHP and MySQL, and I need to SUM the total amount of products joining 3 tables:

**order_products:** (There are multiple order products with the same name but different amounts in the table)

```
order_id        (int)
product_name    (varchar)
product_amount  (int)
```

**orders:**

```
order_id       (int)
order_date     (varchar)
order_status   (varchar)
```

**supplier:**

```
product_name    (varchar)
product_amount  (int)
```

So, I want to show how many products I sold and status is shipped and how many I ordered from the supplier in one single row. Any of two examples below will help me to achieve my goal.

Like:

```
Product Name     (sum order_products)      (sum supplier)  Order status

first product           300                  2500          Shipped_Only
second product          50                   400           Shipped_Only
third product           10                   600           Shipped_Only


Product Name     (sum order_products)      (sum supplier)  Order status

first product           2200                 2500          Not_Shipped
second product          400                  400           Not_Shipped
third product           590                  600           Not_Shipped
```

Are there any examples or other help that I can get to do this?

Edit:
Sample Data goes like this

**order_products:**

```
order_id       product_name     product_amount

255               product 1         200
256               product 1         100
257               product 2         50
258               product 3         10
```

**orders:**
    order_id         order_date     order_status

```
255               09.05.2018         Shipped
256               09.05.2018         Shipped
257               10.05.2018         Not_Shipped
258               10.05.2018         Not_Shipped
```

**supplier:**
    product_name      product_amount

```
product 1         2500        
product 2         400   
product 3         600
```

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: @mickmackusa Edited my question to match with desired values

Comment: I think your expected result is confusing.  257 and 258 are Not Shipped, right?  Please clarify your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a join on the aggregated subselect.

```
SELECT t1.product_name, t1.sum_order_products, t2.supplier_sum, t1.order_status 
FROM (
    SELECT op.product_name, SUM(op.product_amount) sum_order_products, o.order_status
    FROM order_products op
    INNER JOIN orders o ON op.order_id = o.order_id 
    WHERE o.order_status = 'Shipped'
    GROUP BY op.product_name, o.order_status
) t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s.product_name, SUM(s.product_amount) supplier_sum
    FROM supplier s 
    GROUP BY s.product_name
) t2 ON t1.product_name = t2.product_name 
ORDER BY t1.order_status, t1.product_name
```

Comment: @mickmackusa  thanks again ..  for op.sum  ..  advice

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't have a table named "sum_order_products". That is the result i'm willing to get. Please check my sample data.

Comment: sum_order_products  is a column alias  not a table name  and this  column alias  resulting from the subselect...   answer  updated  with the order_products table

Comment: @mickmackusa  . thanks for sqlfiddle  .. answer  updated ..  upvoted  somewhere many thanks

Comment: @mickmackusa  what is a trolled  question ?  .. (I don't find a translation for trolled)  ..  the donwvotes question ?

Comment: Thx. Now what is your resultset?  It looks like a mix of Shipped/non-shipped data.  Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: This happen to me also .. i have only a question  ..and this is the target for revenge

Comment: @scaisEdge I think i got it working. So, can you please alter the code for select only "Shipped" orders in sqlfiddle?

Comment: @zontrakulla  ok .. just a moment

Comment: @mickmackusa  . thanks for the editing in my unique question  .. but i don't think the downvote is for grammar  .. anyway thanks  .

Comment: I think the OP's desired output is confusing me.

Comment: i think that the important part is the concept  .. in this case is better join the aggregated  result  . th OP can use the concept and adapt the code  .. SO should not be a coding service ..

Comment: Thank you for the example. I successfully adapted the code for my table and for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

From What I understand, I think this is what you want, please give more clarity if this is not what you are expecting.

You will need to use GROUP BY clause and them you will have to use count() function to count the number of rows for the results coming from Group By Clause. I am writing an example of how to use a group by clause, you will need to modify the query as per your need.

```
SELECT
 order_products.product_name,
 count(*) as Total_Orders,
 MAX(supplier.product_amount) as Supplier_Amt,
 orders.order_status
FROM supplier
 INNER JOIN order_products ON supplier.product_name = order_products.product_name
 INNER JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = order_products.order_id
WHERE orders.order_status = 'Not_Shipped'
GROUP BY order_products.product_name, orders.order_status;
```

You will need to queries, you can write the other one, just replace `WHERE orders.order_status = 'Not_Shipped'` with `WHERE orders.order_status = 'Shipped'` Also if you want all in a single query, simply remove the where clause.

Comment: Despite the upvote, no resultset.  Have a play: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb76a0/2

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but result is not true. Check the sqlfiddle which @mickmackusa provided. Total_Supplier_Amt is doubled, supposed to be 2500 instead of 5000

Comment: @Candy You are offering a mixed resultset of shipped and non-shipped rows.  I think the OP wants all one way or all the other.

Comment: I think the OP's desired output is confusing me.